Import Error: Unable to Resolve Module from a Subfolder in Python Project Description:
I am working on a Python project with the following folder structure:
NIDS_Proj/
├── modules/
│   ├── login_management.py
│   ├── ...
├── utils/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── hash_utils.py
│   ├── ...

In the file login_management.py, located in the modules folder, I am trying to import functions from hash_utils.py, located in the utils folder, using the following code:
from utils.hash_utils import hash_password, verify_password

However, I get the following error: Unresolved reference 'utils'.
I have already ensured that:
The __init__.py file exists in the utils folder.
Both folders (modules and utils) are in the same parent directory.
What am I missing here? How can I resolve this issue?
I updated Python to the latest version to ensure compatibility.
I checked my Git repository to confirm that all files and directories are properly synced.
I verified the presence of the __init__.py file in the utils folder to ensure it is treated as a module.
I tried running the script directly and also with the -m option (python -m modules.login_management), but the issue persists.
I expected the import to work seamlessly since both modules and utils are in the same parent directory.

You might need to set or update the PYTHONPATH environment variable. You can learn about it in this article, for example. If you open a terminal in your NIDS_Proj folder, the following command could work: PYTHONPATH=. python -m modules.login_management. Could you please try?

Forget about PYTHONPATH - how are you running your project?
